# VSCode debugging: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ts-node

I use VSCode to debug my ts-node TypeScript code. Sometimes this leads to problems that (I guess) stem from the fact that the code which is executed is JavaScript, but the code that I see is TypeScript:

For example, sometimes the variable `foo` gets renamed to `_foo` by the transpiler. Then, I cannot inspect the variable `foo`'s content by hovering over it. Only in the debug window, I see that `foo` got renamed to `_foo`. I guess I have to live with that.

Far more severe are the problems with the Debug Console, which I often use for on-the-fly evaluation of expressions. I have a class `MyClass` that is used in the code I am currently debugging. The class is imported via a

```
import MyClass from './MyClass'
```

or similar. Now I want to use that class in the Debug Console window, while the debugger is paused (e.g. by a breakpoint). Because the class is already imported in the code that is currently debugged, I try it by just using it, like it is used in the current code:

```
MyClass
Uncaught ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined
```

No idea why it is not defined in the current context. So let's try to import it again. Since we are now in JavaScript, let's try `require`:

```
require("./MyClass")
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

- How can it be that `require` is not defined?
- How can I use this class in the Debug Window?

This is not just the Debug Console window, but also affects the Watch Expressions window and probably others.

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283516/require-is-not-defined-in-console-tab-of-node-inspectors-repl) could help

Comment: @EthanVu thanks, that's it indeed.